# Akka Http - multiroutes and simple reflection of code with implicits

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray

I have a simple `Main` object, which create `routes` for my two services this way:

```
object GameApp extends App {

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val host = config.getString("http.host")
  val port = config.getInt("http.port")

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("game-service")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val game = new GameRouting
  val rate = new RateRouting
  val routes: Route = game.route ~ rate.route

  Http().bindAndHandle(routes, host, port) map {
    binding => println(s"Server start on ${binding.localAddress}")
  } recover {
    case ex => println(s"Server could not start on ${host}:${port}", ex.getMessage)
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to refactor this code and move this piece into separate method/class/object etc.:

```
val game = new GameRouting
val rate = new RateRouting
val routes: Route = game.route ~ rate.route
```

But this classes (`GameRouting` and `RateRouting`) uses `implicit` in constructors and I cannot simply move this code to separate place.
How should I refactor this code to get what I want?

My another question is - routes classes (`GameRouting` and `RateRouting`) should be `class` or `case class`? This is `GameRouting` class:

```
trait Protocols extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val gameFormat = jsonFormat4(Game)
}

class GameRouting(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends Protocols {

  val gameService = new GameService

  val route: Route = {
    pathPrefix("games") {
      pathEndOrSingleSlash {
        get {
          complete {
            gameService.getGames()
          }
        } ~
          post {
            entity(as[Game]) { gameForCreate =>
              createGame(gameForCreate)
            }
          }
      } ~
        pathPrefix(LongNumber) { id =>
          get {
            complete {
              gameService.getGame(id)
            }
          } ~ put {
            entity(as[Game]) { gameForUpdate =>
              complete {
                gameService.update(gameForUpdate)
              }

            }
          }
        }
    }
  }

  private def createGame(gameForCreate: Game) = {
    onComplete(gameService.createGame(gameForCreate)) {
      case Success(created) => complete(StatusCodes.Created, created)
      case Failure(exception) => complete(StatusCodes.BadRequest, s"An error: $exception")
    }
  }
}
```

And if I make it `case` I cannot access field `routes` from `Main` object. How to fix this or write it in better way? Maybe there are basic questions, but I've been still learning Scala and Akka since few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move your implicits to separate object:

```
object GameAppImplicits {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("game-service")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
}
```

and then import when needed:

```
import yourpackage.GameAppImplicits._
```

For your second question, case classes are usually used for modeling immutable data. In this case you don't really need any feature, that case classes give you (like automatic `toString`, `equals`, `copy` etc.), so I would say it would be best to just use plain `class`.